No infinite component in $\mathbb Z^2$ percolation implies an open circuit in the dual graph around the origin
I'm trying to make rigorous a geometric argument that seems extremely intuitive, but that I'm not managing to fully formalise.
I'm considering percolation on $\mathbb Z^2$, and whether the origin percolates ie is contained in an infinite component. I'm trying to reason about when infinite components exist, and so am reasoning almost surely - here the dual graph is $\mathbb Z^2 +(0.5,0.5)$, where edges are closed iff their dual edge is open. By "circuit" I mean a loop of edges which encompasses a region.
Clearly, an open dual circuit around the origin in the dual graph implies that the connected component of $(0,0)$ is contained within this circuit - an infinite component would contain an arbitrary length open path from (0,0), which must intersect the circuit.
But even if in my mind the converse is equally intuitive geometrically, I'm finding it much harder to prove precisely: no infinite component feels like it should mean there's a "block" to any paths that would be infinitely long, but I'm not managing to deduce that any specific open dual circuit exists.
Why is this then the case? I'm open to different lines of reasoning, but want to gain insight into why the converse holds.
